# Hiding element space without height constraint

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image]

This is a reuseable tableview cell. I want to hide 3. UILabel from the top, both the element and its space when it has no data.

I can't create a height constraint of it because I need to use it multiline depends on the text.

```
if release.post.isEmpty {

    cell.label3.isHidden = true

} else {

    cell.label3.isHidden = false

}
```

So how can I hide its space without a height constraint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by dynamically adding the constraint

```
cell.match.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                cell.match.constraints.forEach { (constraint) in
                       if constraint.firstAttribute == .height
                       {
                        constraint.constant = release.post.height(withConstrainedWidth: cell.match.frame.width, font: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle.subheadline)) + 15
                       }
                   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the stack view and then hide the required objects i.e label or image. Remember to give the proper constraints to the stack view and select the required properties.

Comment: Should I place a stack view for whole-cell or just for uilabel and image together?